# How do I create inventory files that have my own custom facts (docker_version) in them?

Tags: ansible

Ansible code:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - command: 'docker --version | { read _ _ v _; printf %s\\n "${v%,}"; }'
    register: docker_version

  - debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname].docker_version.stdout
    ignore_errors: true

  - set_fact:
      docker_version: "{{ docker_version.stdout }}"

  - name: Display all variables/facts known for a host
    debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt gather.yml

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [10.x-hosname]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [10.x-hosname] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].docker_version.stdout": "Docker version 1.12.3, build 34a2ead"
}

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [10.x-hosname]

TASK [Display all variables/facts known for a host] ****************************
ok: [10.x-hosname] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname]": {
        "ansible_check_mode": false,
        "ansible_version": {
            "full": "2.2.1.0",
            "major": 2,
            "minor": 2,
            "revision": 1,
            "string": "2.2.1.0"
        },
        "docker_version": "Docker version 1.12.3, build 34a2ead",
        "group_names": [],
        "groups": {
            "all": [
                "10.x-hosname"
            ],
            "ungrouped": []
        },
        "inventory_dir": "/Users/username/Git/gather",
        "inventory_file": "/Users/username/Git/gather/inventory.txt",
        "inventory_hostname": "10.x-hosname",
        "inventory_hostname_short": "10",
        "playbook_dir": ""
    }
}
```

10.x-hosname is the IP address listed in inventory.txt.

I would like this script to create a json inventory file from multiple servers including custom facts like docker_version. The output of the last command of this is exactly what I want to see outputted in a json file, but for multiple hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Make a template (e.g. `facts.j2`):

```
[
{% for host in play_hosts %}
  {{ hostvars[host] | to_nice_json }}
  {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
]
```

Call it as last task:

```
- name: Generate JSON
  template:
    src: facts.j2
    dest: /tmp/facts.json
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: yes
```